# Unable to mongodump on Windows

Tags: windows, mongodb

When running `mongodump` on Windows I get this error:

```
2017-04-10T13:41:46.487-0400    Failed: error dumping metadata: error creating metadata file dump\admin\_Join:users:_Role.metadata.json: open dump\admin\_Join:users:_Role.metadata.json: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

From what I see the problem is with the file name which starts with a `_` 
Is there a way to work-around this issue?

Comment: What version of mongodump are you using, e.g. the output of running ``mongodump --version``?

Comment: C:\Users\paperspace>mongodump --version
mongodump version: built-without-version-string
git version: built-without-git-spec
Go version: go1.7
   os: windows
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1u  22 Sep 2016

Comment: Ugh, looks like there's a bug and it's not outputting the actual version. I would assume that these are 3.4.1 binaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that it's actually a problem with `:` in the filename, underscore should be fine. It looks like you have a collection in your admin database called `_Join:users:_Role`. Did you create this? If you don't need it, you could drop it, or could rename it to something less awkward.

If you actually need to backup that specific collection a workaround would be to dump to stdout and redirect the output to a file:

You might also try dumping to an archive file, using the `--archive` option.